# Jasper report to add common header/footer in every report/default header footer set in all report

Tags: jasper-reports

In my project I need to create multiple reports but all the reports have one thing in common the header/footer and style.

**Header/Footer -** All reports has same header footer with logo's and some information. Only thing will change is the report name and few other information like dates.

**Style** - All reports have same styles like font, color combination including for multiple row of the records one row color is deep and one light.

Now as the above mentioned parts are common I would like to create a common files or files and for every report the same thing will be included.

One thing I found that sub report can do the task but not sure how it will be done. So, any help will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set default style and use external styles

Comment: Yes, you can use subreport for rendering same header and footer

Comment: Can you provide some example for the both approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use  Page Header and Page Footer Bands as in ReportInspector Tool[image: snap shot of NetbeansEditor]